# Drag and Drop directly from Outlook to a webform

Tags: asp.net, vba, outlook, drag-and-drop

I searched online and mostly found answers that it cannot be done.

My case is a bit different as the application we are developing is for an in-house purposes only and can allow any security level in the browser. Its also intranet based.

I also tried to see if there is a ready-made activex control but wasn't able to find one that will allow dragging directly from outlook.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify exactly *what* you want to drag and drop from Outlook. An email message? A contact? I assume you want more than just some text, because most browsers now allow you to drag and drop into a text box to automatically paste some text.

Comment: As an alternative to drag and drop, an outlook macro can save the HTML body of a message (say the selected message) as a file which would be displayable by every browser I have tried.  Would this approach be of interest?

Comment: Yes please be more specific. What do you want to drag and drop? Outlook version? Why does drag and drop involve ASP and/or VBA?

Comment: Trying to drag and drop the entire outlook message (not only the text) on the webpage and save it to a DB.

Comment: The text and html bodies and all the header fields (sender, recipient, bcc, dates, subject, etc.) are available to an outlook macro as strings.  I have never tried, but I assume a table of header fields could be inserted after the body tag if it was essential to create a single unit.  I archive all my emails.  I save the header fields in a database row and have hyperlinks to the bodies and attachments which I save as regular files.

Comment: what's you have to involve drag-and-drop, have you considered altertives?. like access to the Outlook Objects via a Server-Side ActiveX and retrieve the message? (only brainstorming not neccesary it's possible)

Comment: I tried the same thing. It works great if I drag the message from outlook to my desktop and then the resulting file from my desktop to the browser, but no dice dragging directly from outlook to the browser. Given that this was just an additional possible benefit of the drag and drop feature we're working on, its an adequate workaround, but not a feature we'll be advertising as a result. Dragging attachments from an email, unfortunately has the same result. This was tested in chrome 24.0.1312.52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I found is to just create an Add-In for Outlook to add the email to our database.

Comment: Hi. Do you still have access to that add-in? I can sure, use that.

Answer (score 2):

I found this sample [WebApp](http://codebits.glennjones.net/dragdrop/contenteditable.htm) where you can drag and drop Outlook Contacts to an HTML5 WebForm.

If you drag an Outlook Message directly from Outlook to the WebForm you can drop it, but nothing happens. Maybe with a little tweaking you can get it to work with Messages too.

regards

Comment: I don't think this will work for emails. When dragging a contact the "e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')" contains full information as string. When dragging an email, you only see the information displayed in your messages list: From, Subject, Received etc, email body is not available unless you add "Message" column in your Outlook messages list view. Attachments would not be available anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AT this moment drag-and-drop API in Internet Explorer Browser isn't supported, Microsoft will implement it in IE 10, but i don't know if Drag-And-Drop API will bring you with the functionality that you are looking for.

[HTML5 Drag and Drop in IE10 PPB2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/27/html5-drag-and-drop-in-ie10-ppb2.aspx)

For the rest of browsers the API implementation is incomplete

i recomend you to considere alternatives to this approach